# JMS queue as a backend of Azure API

Tags: azure-api-management

I could front an http REST API with Azure API Manager and call it.

Is there a way to front a JMS queue by an API?

1) To add a request to a JMS queue by calling the Azure proxy API

2) To read the response from another queue and deliver back to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Only if JMSQ has an HTTP API, not sure if it does.
2. In general it would be really hard to make APIM wait for arbitrary event holding on to a client's request to provide an HTTP response. So I'm inclined to say no.